# Java - Loading background music into memory

Tags: java, music, memory-efficiency, memory

I am currently developing a game with Java, with a soundtrack consisting of ten tracks in .ogg format, 1-2 MB in size each. To be able to switch between these tracks quickly and easily in the game, before the game starts, I load all of them into memory by creating ten `Clip` classes. Unfortunately, but understandably, pre-loading these tracks increases the application's CPU usage from about 61 MB to 340 MB.

Since I'm only ever playing one track at a time, I could make it so that only one `Clip` is ever in memory, and is destroyed when the track needs to change. This means, though, that I'll have to hang the game up on loading the `Clip` when this happens, or do this on a different thread during a few seconds of undesirable silence.

Is there a smarter, more conventional way to handle large BGM files, or do I just have to pick my poison?

Comment: Could you stream the tracks from the disk instead of loading them to the memory? Google for OggInputStream.

Comment: Am I able to pause an OggInputStream without delay as I am with Clips?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method is to only keep *2 tracks* in memory; one playing and one ready to be played.

When one track is done you start the next one and also start loading the track (in a background thread) to be played after that one and `close()` the Clip that just finished.